# Netbeans - how to set background image via CSS url property

Tags: html, css, image, url, netbeans

My image not inserting. Please help. Here are my HTML and code below.

I'm using **Netbeans IDE**.

**HTML**

```
<main class="clock">

  <div class="hour-container">
    <div class="hour"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="minute-container">
    <div class="minute"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="second-container">
     <div class="second"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
.clock {
 background: url(../img/ios_clock.svg);
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-size: 88%;
}
```

[Here is the project file structure. ]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bei66.png

Comment: @CertainPerformance done sir. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

in image you forget `'`

please enter in your css file :

```
background-image: url('your-images-url');
```

for more information visit this link :
 [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Comment: I tested your code. It has no problem.
The only problem is that you should not use the svg file instead of png

Comment: for use svg in html files :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011289/how-to-use-svg-files-in-a-webpage